# Breakpoints ignored in Safari 7

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, breakpoints

I'm having trouble debugging JavaScript in Safari 7, the breakpoints I put in are just being ignored. I know you enable/disable all break points and they are definitely enabled. It just isn't stopping code execution at all!

Anyone else experienced this? Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure the code is getting to the breakpoints?

Comment: Fair point but yes, because I've added console.log – which is what I was trying to avoid doing.

Comment: What are you setting the breakpoints on?

Comment: Lines of a minified js file that is prettified by Safari

Comment: As of Safari 7.0.5 I'm still having this same problem.

Comment: It seems to have calmed down for me. I think some of the problem was that the inspector would get disconnected somehow from the browser tab, so it simply no longer had an affect on it. If you close the inspector and reopen it it works again for a while.

Answer (score 21):

Maybe you disable breakpoints:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Debugger/Debugger.html

> By clicking the breakpoint icon in the Breakpoints pane, you disable
>   all breakpoints. The breakpoint locations are still saved, but
>   JavaScript runs as if no breakpoints are set. Disabled breakpoints
>   have a grayed-out appearance,

[image: Disable breakpoints]

[image: Enable breakpoints]

Comment: Yeah, been aware of that. Seems intermittent. Sometime they work and sometimes they don't tried disabling and enabling. I would have thought I was doing something wrong, but I can use breakpoints fine in Chrome and Firefox, so I don't think it's a user error!

Answer (score 2):

A reboot of Safari fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the breakpoint, and adding `e.preventDefault()` as code to be evaluated when the breakpoint matches.