# How to debug clicking/tapping of links in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari, developer-tools, ios8.3

Is there a way to prevent MobileSafari from continuing on the path of navigating to a new URL whenever I am debugging a complex interaction that involves an anchor tag with a valid HREF attribute?

I'm developing some Javascript code and testing click/touch events on an iPad.  I've got Safari's Dev Tools on my Mac communicating with Mobile Safari on iPad with no issue.  My issue looks like the following:

- On the iPad, I click an  tag that can do some complex interactions (tap vs. long-press, etc).
- Safari's dev tools break at my breakpoint, directly inside the event handler
- The iPad continues to follow the link even though the javascript code is broken.

For example:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('wtf');
  // ...Handler Code...
});
```

Setting a breakpoint in Safari Dev Tools on the `console.log()` statement will break the Javascript as expected, but the browser will continue to navigate to the link's address, causing the page to change.  This effectively keeps me from debugging any interactions involving a link click.

However, if you `preventDefault()` on the event, Safari will not continue (which is what would happen if I wasn't debugging):

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('wtf');
  // ...Handler Code...
});
```

This is very different from how Chrome/Firefox/IE handle this style of debugging.  Is this a bug in MobileSafari or Safari Dev Tools, or am I missing something?

Comment: ***e.preventDefault()*** is just stopping the browser from redirecting you to the ***href***.

Comment: Right, but my point was that if my code hits a breakpoint in Dev Tools, it shouldn't be redirecting to the href at all, but it currently is.

Comment: This maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20142121/2628694

Comment: The issue looks related but I can confirm my breakpoints are enabled.  The other solution there was "restart Safari", which I've also done

Comment: @EdwardCoyleJr. Did you ever find a solution to this? Ran into this same issue today.

Comment: @chrisn, sorry!  I never found a solution to this.  I think it may just be a bug with Safari dev tools that hasn't yet been fixed.  The best solution I found was to temporarily use `e.preventDefault()` on the click handler.

Comment: @EdwardCoyleJr. I am running into the same issue, but `e.preventDefault()` isn't helping! Any other tips?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't come up with any other answers here.  Sorry!